# Create home directory from skeleton upon FTP first login

Tags: ftp

Using `pure-ftpd` and its `-j` switch, it is possible to have the user's home directory created upon his first login:

> `-j`: If the home directory of a user doesn't exist, automatically create it. The newly created home directory belongs to the user, and permissions are set according  to  the current directory mask. To avoid local attacks, the parent directory should never belong to an untrusted user.

Given this, is it possible to create the home directory based on a predefined skeleton (`/etc/skel` for instance) ?

Comment: That seems specific to pure-ftpd, the commonly used approach it to use `pam_mkhomedir` which can copy skel.

Comment: Unfortunately, logging in through FTP does not trigger `pam_mkhomedir`. My application requires me to use my own authentication module, which does not rely on PAM.

Answer (score 0):

After contacting the PureFTPd mailing list, it turns out that no such feature is available. While the creation of the directory can be handled by PureFTPd, it does not allow the system administrator to populate it with a skeleton at the same time.

Two solutions remain however:

- Configure PureFTPd so that its authentication process goes through PAM. This way, you can schedule `pam_mkhomedir` somewhere in your chain (and use its `skel` option).
- If you use your own authentication module, adapt it so it can take care of the process itself when an authentication attempt suceeds and the home directory is nowhere to be found.